# How can I refactor CSS safely?

Tags: html, css, refactoring

I'm maintaining a site with dozens of CSS files and getting burned all the time because it's so hard to predict the site-wide effect of changing a style. The styles combine and cascade in extremely complex ways and it's getting to be a real problem.

What I would really like is a tool that could scan the project and identify actual CSS usage, so that I could find dead styles with confidence, or know where something is used. Ideally, this would hook into the IDE, so if I removed or renamed a style that's in use, I would get an error message.

Is there a tool like this, and if not, what are some best practices for addressing this problem?

(Note: I use less and know all about creating styles cleanly; this question is about how to deal with existing messy CSS reliably.)